# How to encrypt QR Code with java

Tags: java, android, qr-code

How do I encrypt a QR Code with java?

Now I can generate and decode QR code with java base
but I want to know how to put a password on my qrcode to protect it or encrypt my qrcode with something

Has anyone done something similar or is there sample code available?

Thank you so much

Comment: My proposal is to encrypt the data at first and then put them into QR code.

Comment: QRCode is just a bitmap, so you can always get the byte data and encrypt it using any encryption algorithm. But as Yury suggested, you should be encrypting the data, not sure why you want to encrypt the image itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can put any data you like in a QR code.  For example
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&chld=M|1&chl=abc123
Will produce a code with the data abc123.

Once you have your encrypted data, you can then generate a QR code.

For example, this QR code https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsFdQ.png

Contains the message

> -----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
>
> Version: GnuPG v1.4.5 (FreeBSD)
>
> Comment: This is what your message looks like after encryption.
>
> hQEOA1e+1x6YuUMCEAP+J/+0smoM/5aWiJZ7r+WsVKwbQ4xYJ1ftqGePeM5EnCAR
>
> 3d+Ai/4A3be615RFQ636RguSjJIKuoJCaHt/P6LH78ZX3xmOwucpmNYBCv1wN15X
>
> gpdhOxtBnAx1aqI7sbrfTarKsZIY2Aqblgarq71dr0Kv7wCu1eGCg1YK7O2keOED
>
> /AqTH8US94iceM9bRGIGk/SubV1e0Fw/kMc4J5wr2JHbifD+yNQvKIC87lQydLlC
>
> 2ZqOB2ed2OKsplB3zuoaWgV1skhRimLubehxkkJpiooKVVVnhVJh0w6kHWrYTV7T
>
> MOSaduQBakPNoDUGIhvDkpU8N6uUs7F1xvr7vwoIim4C0kYBaDolzRjgmOq0QfvN
>
> vF3Rc6ZlFqCfihpQgAAmboHa/uZxE0cP37UssaL6O0beLhCHWH/X8sUeEHmXEHLh
>
> J+tL3EaO750a
>
> =c8iI
>
> -----END PGP MESSAGE-----

You may need to make sure there are line breaks when generating the data.

There is no way, that I am aware of, to password protect a QR. The best you could do is point it to a URL and then ask for a password on the website.

Answer (score -1):

it can be password protected, see [uvsar.org](http://uvsar.blogspot.com/2009/05/secure-qr-and-qm-codes.html), this is an article about secure QR and QM codes